# Java: successful build but the output is "user_package.Point@68e26d2e"

Tags: java, class, methods

I am learning java and trying to execute a simple script. I have a class `Point` as the following:

```
package user_package;

public class Point {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    public Point(float x, float y, float z){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public static Point add(Point p1, Point p2){
        return new Point(p1.x + p2.x, p1.y + p2.y, p1.z + p2.z);
    }
}
```

Then I have the main file like this:

```
import user_package.Point;
import static user_package.Point.add;

class Tutorial{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        float x1 = 1, y1 = 1, z1 = 1;
        float x2 = 2, y2 = 2, z2 = 2;

        Point p1 = new Point(x1, y1, z1);
        Point p2 = new Point(x2, y2, z2);

        Point p3 = add(p1, p2);

        System.out.println(p3);
    }
}
```

I do this in Netbeans. It gives me no errors and the build is successful but the output is:

```
user_package.Point@68e26d2e
```

I tried to search myself but nothing found. Please tell me what the problem is and how I can solve it.

Comment: That's expected. What's the problem?

Comment: you need to override `toString()`

Comment: Thank you all for the answers

Comment: @Alexandr. its better to upvote all the answers which were useful to you and accept one which you find the most appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
 System.out.println(p3);
```

There `toString()`  calls on the Object you passed.

Since you didn't provide any implementation there,

You have to ovveride the `toString()`  method in your `Point` class.

[As per docs of toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object.

So

```
 user_package.Point@68e26d2e  is the textual representation of Point class.
```

To get the  required output, write the logic in overridden `toString` method in Object class and  return the string there.

```
package user_package;

    public class Point {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;

        public Point(float x, float y, float z){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }

        public static Point add(Point p1, Point p2){
            return new Point(p1.x + p2.x, p1.y + p2.y, p1.z + p2.z);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
          StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
             result.append(this.x).append(",");  
             result.append(this.y).append(",");
             result.append(this.z)
             return result.toString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not overridden `toString` method for `Point` class so the `Object` class `toString` method is called. **If you want meaningful textual representation of your object, override `toString`**

```
public String toString(){

   return "stringYouWantToReturn";

}
```

In your case, add this to `Point` class

```
public String toString() {
        return "Point [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + ", z=" + z + "]";
    }
```

When you print an object using `println` method, `toString()` is implicitly called.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing object of class `Point`. If `println()` method doesn't know how to print a class, it prints its name. That's why you get such result.

You can do it either like this:

```
System.out.println(p3.x + ", " + p3.y + ", " + p3.z);
```

Or as SURESH ATTA suggested, by overriding `toString()` method for your `Point` class (or in other words - learning your `Point` class to know how to behave when you want to print it).

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `toString()` function in `Point` class or create user defined function in `Point` class.
Using `toString()` method

```
public class Point {

public String toString()
{
//your code goes here
return "Point "+ "X : "+ x +"Y : "+ y + "Z : "+z;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers already implicitly stated

```
  System.out.println(p3);
```

actually is

```
  System.out.println(p3.toString());
```

and since you are not providing an own implementation for the `toString()` method. The default implementation of [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) is called. Which results in your given output. In order to change that behaviour you have to override `toString()`

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Point: x=" + x + ", y=" + y + ", z=" + z;
}
```