# Java arraylist not returning correct data

Tags: java, arraylist

so I've created an arraylist in my main class called:

```
private static ArrayList<Job> teamNoOne = new ArrayList<Job>();
```

It's of type Job which is in another java file with the variables;

```
public class Job {
    public long time;
    public int teamNo;
    public String regNo;
    public String gridRef;
}
```

When the user inputs data into a textfield, I get the text entered and save it under one of the variables and add it to an arraylist.

```
Job job = new Job();
job.gridRef = tfGridRef.getText();
```

when I add the data to the array `(teamNoOne.add(job.gridRef);` I keep getting an error

> The method add(Job) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add an String to an arraylist of Job objects in the following statement:

```
(teamNoOne.add(job.gridRef));
```

because `job.gridRef` is a `String` and not a `Job` object.

You should try to add the `Job` objects to the list, something like this:

```
Job job = new Job();
job.gridRef = tfGridRef.getText();

teamNoOne.add(job);
```

Comment: just a quick question, I've done it like that and its working, but when I get the first value from the array (index 0) it's only returning "Job@a56214", and not the data? 

Cheers

Comment: @user2761143 Look here, This is the problem you are facing now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975141/java-successful-build-but-the-output-is-user-package-point68e26d2e/18975178#18975178

Comment: @user2761143 You need to override the toString method in order to print it in a pretty way. Try to search about implementing toString method.

Answer (score 1):

You declared your `Collection(list)` telling that have only `Job` object's and trying to add `String's`.

You have to add Job object

```
List<Job> teamNoOne = new ArrayList<Job>();
```

and then

```
teamNoOne.add(job);  //adding job obj //correct

teamNoOne.add(job.gridRef);  //adding String/ wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `ArrayList` is a collection of *Job* object, you need to add/append specific *Job* on it.

```
Job job = new Job();
job.gridRef = tfGridRef.getText();

teamNoOne.add(job);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create an array list of some object type, you have to pass the same type of objects to the add method,

```
 ArrayList<ObjectType> arrayListName = new ArrayList<ObjectType>();
   arrayListName.add(objectOfGivenType);
```

So what you have to do is assign the values to the Job object and then you can add it to the array list as above.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `job.gridRef` is a `String`  but as you can see that from
`private static ArrayList<Job> teamNoOne = new ArrayList<Job>();`, `teamNoOne` is list of `Job`. Which mean `teamNoOne` require `Job` object. So try like this:

```
Job job = new Job();
job.gridRef = tfGridRef.getText();
teamNoOne.add(job);
```